# Uncaught OAuthException - how to catch this error?

Tags: php, api, facebook-graph-api, error-handling, facebook-oauth

I have the below error.  How am I supposed to catch this error?

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating access token:
>   User 638720122 has not authorized application 207445576002891. thrown
>   in
>   /var/www/clients/client1/web12/web/socialmediaping/fblibrary/base_facebook.php
>   on line 1039

I have the below snippet of code where I beleive I do attempt to manage the error.

```
// Attempt to query the graph:
$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?"
  . "access_token=" . $access_token;
$response = curl_get_file_contents($graph_url);
$decoded_response = json_decode($response);

//Check for errors 
if ($decoded_response->error) {
    $facebookAuth = FALSE;
}
```

Further down I redirect the user to facebook to authoise if $facebookAuth == FALSE but this isnt working, so What should I be doing?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dont screw your base_facebook.php! Simply use a try/catch block around your graph calls:

```
try {

    // check if facebook can get user
    $facebookUser = $facebook->getUser();
    $facebookUser = $facebook->api('me?fields=id,first_name,last_name');

} catch (Exception $e) {
    // user is not logged in
}
```